# Problema em Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, contador

Olá, sou (muito) novo em Python e gostaria de saber o que há de errado com o meu código simples (para aprender Python):

```
eleitores = (int(input('Digite o total de eleitores: ')))
c = 0
cand_a = 0
cand_b = 0
cand_c = 0
opcao = 0
print('''CANDIDATOS:
PARA VOTAR NO CANDIDATO A DIGITE 1
PARA VOTAR NO CANDIDATO B DIGITE 2
PARA VOTAR NO CANDIDATO C DIGITE 3 ''')
while c < eleitores:
    while opcao == 1 or 2 or 3:
        c = c + 1
        opcao = int(input(f'Digite a opção do {c} eleitor: '))
        if opcao == 1:
            cand_a = cand_a + 1
        elif opcao == 2:
            cand_b = cand_b + 1
        elif opcao == 3:
            cand_c = cand_c + 1
    else:
         opcao = int(input('Comando inválido. Digite novamente: '))
else:
    print(f'O número de votos no candidato A foi de {cand_a} eleitores, '
         f'o número de votos no candidato B foi de {cand_b} eleitores e '
         f'o número de votos no candidato C foi de {cand_c} eleitores.')
```

O problema é que ele não para de perguntar a opção do meu voto com o número de eleitores que insiro, ele fica perguntando 'para sempre'.
Tenham em mente que eu ainda não sei usar outras funções do Python além de if, for e while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Erro na linha 12:** Você escreveu `while opcao == 1 or 2 or 3:`. Nessa linha você não está dizendo **"Se opção for 1, 2 ou 3, faça."**, você está dizendo **"Se opção for 1, faça. Caso não, se 2, faça. Caso não, se 3, faça."**.

O operador `or` irá retornar `True` se uma das condições for verdade (True). Em `Python`, todos os números são tratados como `True` exceto o **0** que é tratado como `False`.

A primeira condição talvez não fosse verdade, mas as outras com certeza seriam pois no `or 2 or 3`, as condições estão separadas e os número 2 e 3 sozinhos são `True`. Logo o bloco `while` nunca iria acabar. Para corrigir isto você tem 2 opções:

**Opção 1:**

```
while opcao == 1 or opcao == 2 or opcao == 3:
```

**Opcao 2: ( Ainda não é pra você porque você precisaria aprender sobre lista e operador "in" )**

```
while opcao in [1,2,3]:
```

Agora seguindo o seu objetivo, a pergunta da opção sempre iria se repetir pois o `while` repete o código enquanto uma condição for verdadeira (True), ou seja, mesmo que a opção escolhida pelo o usuário fosse a correta (1,2,3), o código iria se repetir porque a condição é `opcao == 1 or opcao == 2 or opcao ==3`.

Para que o código não seja repetido caso o usuário coloque a opção correta, você deverá trocar o sinal de comparação `==` por `!=`.

**OUTROS ERROS:**

O `else` não funciona com `while`. Quando você acaba o bloco ele vai direto para a linha do `else`. Se você deseja usa-lo, terá que colocar um `if`.

No início do código, não é necessário você fechar o `int` com parênteses, apesar disso não gerar nenhum problema. É melhor você fazer `int(input('Digite o total de eleitores: '))`

O programa nunca sairá da primeira repetição ( primeiro while ), porque a condição `c < eleitores` sempre será `True`, já que a variável `c` não pode ser alterada pois a condição do segundo `while` (onde a variável é alterada) será `False`.

**CÓDIGO CORRIGIDO E MELHORADO:**

```
c = 0
opcao = 0
cand_a = 0
cand_b = 0
cand_c = 0

print('''CANDIDATOS:
PARA VOTAR NO CANDIDATO A DIGITE 1
PARA VOTAR NO CANDIDATO B DIGITE 2
PARA VOTAR NO CANDIDATO C DIGITE 3 ''')

while c < 3:
    while opcao != 1 and opcao != 2 and opcao != 3::
        c = c + 1
        opcao = int(input(f'\nDigite a opção do {c} eleitor: '))
        if opcao == 1:
            cand_a = cand_a + 1
        elif opcao == 2:
            cand_b = cand_b + 1
        elif opcao == 3:
            cand_c = cand_c + 1
        else:
            print("A opção que você digitou é inválida.")
    opcao = 0

print(f'\nO número de votos no candidato A foi de {cand_a} eleitores.')
print(f'O número de votos no candidato B foi de {cand_b} eleitores.')
print(f'O número de votos no candidato C foi de {cand_c} eleitores.')
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Sem problema :)

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você pretende desenvolver um programa para `"contar"` a quantidade de votos de cada um dos `candidatos`.

Uma das forma mais simples para se resolver esta questão é utilizando o seguinte algoritmo...

```
print('=' * 50)
print(f'\033[34m{f"Eleição":^50}')
print()
print(f'{f"1 - Beltrano":^50}')
print(f'{f"2 - Fulano":^48}')
print(f'{f"3 - Sicrano":^50}\033[m')
print('=' * 50)

eleitores = int(input('Digite o total de eleitores: '))
cont1 = cont2 = cont3 = 0
for c in range(1, eleitores + 1):
    opcao = input(f'Digite a opção do {c}º eleitor: ').strip()
    while opcao not in '123':
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas "1", "2" ou "3"!\033[m')
        opcao = input(f'Digite a opção do {c}º eleitor: ').strip()
    if opcao == '1':
        cont1 += 1
    elif opcao == '2':
        cont2 += 1
    elif opcao == '3':
        cont3 += 1

print(f'\033[32mQuantidade de votos de "Beltrano": {cont1}')
print(f'Quantidade de votos de "Fulano": {cont2}')
print(f'Quantidade de votos de "Sicrano": {cont3}\033[m')
```

Você pode verificar o funcionamento deste programa no [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/cqyplpfb-solkarped).

Observe que este programa recebe a `quantidade de eleitores`, depois, captura a `opção` da votação de cada um dos eleitores, `conta` a quantidade de votos de cada candidato e, em seguida, exibe a `soma` de votos de cada candidato.